# Should the data set documentation have same name the file in use_data_raw in R pakcages?

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

The documentation for a data set should be included in the R dicrectory as an .R file. The `data-raw` directory also includes .R files. Should they be named exactly the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R files don't need the same name.  My documentation R file (saved in the `R` folder) is always called `data.R`.  In the data.R file you may document 1 or more data sets.  In the code below, a data frame named `trial` is documented

```r
#' Results from a simulated trial of Placebo vs Drug
#'
#' A dataset containing the baseline characteristics of 200 patients
#' randomized to Placebo or Drug.  Dataset also contains the trial outcome:
#' tumor response to the treatment.
#'
#' @format A data frame with 200 rows--one row per patient
#' \describe{
#'     \item{trt}{Treatment Randomization}
#'     \item{age}{Age, yrs}
#'     \item{marker}{Marker Level, ng/mL}
#'     \item{stage}{T Stage}
#'     \item{grade}{Grade}
#'     \item{response}{Tumor Response}
#'     \item{death}{Patient Died}
#'     \item{ttdeath}{Months to Death/Censor}
#' }
"trial"
```

The `trial` data set named should be shared by the `trial.rda` file saved in the `data` folder, however.